# What should be the right format for dates in CV?

Tags: cv, formatting

I saw that most of the formats for month & year is like "September 2017"; however it is kind of cluttered. I'm wondering if the following formats are OK:

- Sept. 2017
- 09/2017
- 9/2017

Comment: Are you talking about publication? or what else? Why do you need so many dates such that it is making it cluttered. Why do you think Sept. 2017 won't make it cluttered, if September does? Chose the once which best describe the purpose. It is user dependent. Don't overthink on such minute details. Nobody cares.

Answer (score 4):

There's no right or wrong choice here because there are no formal standards at most universities for what a CV should look like. Just pick one you like and use it throughout the CV.

Comment: To be fair, there is a formalized [international standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for dates. It is not often used among humans, and many would consider weird a couple of its features (such as the `T` between date and time), but there is one.

Comment: @Axel: CV's are not normally covered by the corporate design of a university. They are _personal_ documents, not institutional ones.